# Closest element to a value (Elementwise, numpy array)

Tags: python, numpy, min, minimum, closest

I used to use `min([a, b], key=lambda x:abs(x-x0))` to find which of `a` and `b` are the closest to `x0`.

```
a = 1
b = 2
x0 = 1.49
print(min([a, b], key=lambda x:abs(x-x0)))
# >>> 1
```

Now, `a` and `b` are numpy arrays with an arbitrary number of dimensions. I would like to build an array composed of the closest values to x0 between both arrays, element by element.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 5]])
b = np.array([[6, 2], [6, 2]])

## case 1
x0 = 4
# >>> should return np.array([[6, 2], [3, 5]])

## case 2
x0 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
# >>> should return np.array([[1, 2], [3, 5]])
```

To find the elementwise minimum between two arrays, we can use `numpy.minimum`.
Unfortunately, it does not take `lambda` functions as arguments.

How should I do ?

Comment: `arbitrary number of dimensions` is somewhat arbitrary. Are their dimensions equal, and how do they relate to the dimension of `x0`? Do you have a sample in hand?

Comment: In my case, `x0` is a single float. The dimensions of `a` and `b` should not play in this problem, as soon as `a.shape == b.shape`, right ?

Comment: Can you add [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
np.where(np.abs(a - x0) < np.abs(b - x0), a, b)
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake: `np.abs(a - x0) < np.abs(a - x0)` should be `np.abs(a - x0) < np.abs(b - x0)` right ?

Comment: This works only for two points `a` and `b` and my solution works for any list of points.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` doesn't support a key function. A possible fix is storing distances in a separate array and determining index of smallest distance with [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html). An example with 4D points:

```
points = np.array([[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [3, 4, 5, 5], [6, 4.5, 1, 1]])
x0 = [3, 0.5, 5, 5]
distances = np.sum((points - x0)**2, axis=1)
output = points[np.argmin(distances)]
```

**Output:**

```
array([3., 4., 5., 5.])
```